# Reminder to open the app give feedback

Tags: ios, swift, reminders, rating-system

My app directs people to specific location by passing the data within the app to the native map application. I want to set a reminder to the user to come back and rate the venue that they have just gone to within the app but, I'm not sure how to get this done.

I'm thinking about having notification get sent to the user's device that would segue them to a rating page but, I'm not sure how to do get that done. Any advice or direction would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fire **local notification** once the user reaches the location. The **fire time interval** can be 12hrs or 24 hrs depending on your requirements.

Once the user **taps** on **notification** you can open the app and **redirects** him to **rating page**.

Comment: How would I attach the redirect to the rating page? I have a local notification that brings the user back to the app but, I'm not sure of how to include the redirect.

Comment: Refer this https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/